# sql remove rows from multi tables with duplicate column value

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I had search a lot before that post and here is my qustion:

Tables:

```
table1 
table2
table3
table4
table5
table6
table7
table8
table9
table10
```

Table 1 has:

```
id (primary key), cola, colb, colc
```

In table 1 cola has duplicated *cola* column value:

```
abc
abc
```

In table2:

```
wid (it's id from table1), cola, colb, colc
```

Table3:

```
wid (it's id from table1), cola, colb, colc, cold
```

and so on, all tables content wid.

What I am trying to do is delete the duplicated row depend on column *cola* from table1 and leave only 1. Then delete the rows from the tables table2, table3, table4, table5, ... with in the same id of deleted duplicated row from table1.

Comment: Any ON DELETE CASCADE FK's?

Comment: I think you can use rank over()

Answer (score 0):

Lets see if I can help.

To find the dupes you could use partition and add a rownumber:

```
WITH FindDupes AS (
  SELECT[[id],  
     row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY cola ORDER BY id) AS [rn]
  FROM Table1
)
SELECT * FROM FindDupes WHERE [rn] > 1
```

This way you can find all the duplicated row ID's.

You could also expand the query to delete those's ID's in all tables.

```
WITH DeleteDupes AS (
  SELECT[[id],  
     row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY cola ORDER BY id) AS [rn]
  FROM Table1
)
DELETE t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6, t7, t8, t9, t10 FROM
     table1 as t1
     INNER JOIN table2 as t2 on t1.id = t2.wid
     INNER JOIN table3 as t3 on t1.id = t3.wid
     INNER JOIN table4 as t4 on t1.id = t4.wid
     INNER JOIN table5 as t5 on t1.id = t5.wid
     INNER JOIN table6 as t6 on t1.id = t6.wid
     INNER JOIN table7 as t7 on t1.id = t7.wid
     INNER JOIN table8 as t8 on t1.id = t8.wid
     INNER JOIN table9 as t9 on t1.id = t9.wid
     INNER JOIN table10 as t10 on t1.id = t10.wid
WHERE t1.id in (SELECT id FROM DeleteDupes WHERE [rn] > 1)
```

This leaves one row of the duplicates and removes all others from all 10 tables.
You did not specify which of the duplicates should remain. If you would like to modify this you can do this by changing the ORDER BY clause. The one to keep should be to first result in the ORDER BY clause.